# Может ли слово ВЕК выступать в качестве наречия?

Tags: морфология, части-речи, наречия

Во фразе:

> Я тебя **век** не видел!

К какой части речи относится слово *век*? Уточняя вопрос: является ли оно в данном контексте наречием?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном контексте *век* — существительное, употребленное в разговорном значении "в течение очень долгого времени". Просмотрев словари (БЭС, "Активный словарь русского языка", "Комплексный словарь русского языка" и др.), можно обнаружить, что в подобных контекстах (*Век тебя не видела* и т. п.) **адвербализации** (перехода слова в разряд наречия) **не происходит**.

Однако, на мой взгляд, в таких случаях слово все-таки близко к наречию, ведь в подобных фразах оно не изменяется, "застыло" в вин. ед., ср.: *Не видеть бы тебя век* (в зн. "никогда"), *Он её век не видел*, *Вообще, век не виделись*.

В БТС:

> **Век**, *в зн. нареч. Разг.* 1. Всегда, вечно. *Твою доброту век буду помнить.* 2. (в отрицат. предл.). Никогда. *Век не забуду этой встречи*. Века́ми, в зн. нареч. (4 зн.). Веково́й (см.).

В МАС:

> *в знач. нареч. Разг.* Всегда, вечно. *— Тебя, мой куманек, век слушать я
>   готова.* И. Крылов, Кукушка и Петух. *— Я не ломал, — отвечал Захар, —
>   она [спинка у дивана] сама изломалась; не век же ей быть; надо
>   когда-нибудь изломаться.* И. Гончаров, Обломов. *Уж лучше бы век учиться
>   да не уезжать, не расставаться с матушкой.* Л. Толстой, Детство.

То есть словари фиксируют "наречность" слова *век*, но только со значением "вечно, всегда". В БТС также указывается наречное значение "никогда", однако в "Активном словаре русского языка" оно объединяется с "очень долгое время" и не считается наречным.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51907/discussion-on-answer-by-aer--------).

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря: **ВЕК**, м. 4. Разг. Очень долгое время. Не видеть кого-л. целый век.

**Сравним два существительных: час и век**. Он ждал **час** и еще четверть часа. [Ю. К. Олеша. Альдебаран (1931)]. Твою доброту **век** буду помнить.

**Оба существительных** являются **обстоятельством времени с количественным значением** (как долго?, сколько?).  Разница между ним в метафоричности (образности) слова "век": всю жизнь, очень долго.

На века, на век вперед ―  падежные форма существительного.  А вот навек (= навсегда) , вовек (= всегда, вечно) ―  это наречия.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не совсем корректно сформулирован.
Можно задавать вопрос, какой частью речи является слово, но в предложении слово прежде всего - член предложения. Иногда такой вопрос оправдан, поскольку одно слово может быть отнесено к разным частям речи - и только по контексту можно судить к кокой именно.

Со словом "век" этого, очевидно, не происходит.
Вообще почти все слова, обозначающие единицу времени, равно некоторые другие единицы мер, включая нестандартные и неконкретные (мешок, вагон, море) всегда остаются существительными. При этом в том случае, когда они, часто с предлогом и числительным, отвечают на вопрос типа "сколько?" "как много?" и т.п.,   они в предложении играют роль обстоятельства. В таких случаях говорят о "существительном в наречном значении". Термин, видимо, не совсем удачен, поскольку при этом велик соблазн считать эти слова этакими "начинающими" обстоятельствами, но в принципе он понятен. **Часть речи - существительное, член предложения - обстоятельство.** Или существительное в роли обстоятельства времени.

То, что эти слова могут быть использованы в переносном значении (век=очень долго, вагон - очень много), ни на какие грамматические свойства не влияет.

Вот посмотрите, вполне сносная табличка, пусть и не из авторитетного издания.
http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/720-251_osnovnye_vidy_obstoyatelstv.html